# Does anyone knows how to make SfCalendar's week view pretty?

Tags: xamarin, syncfusion

I'm working with Xamarin Forms and Syncfusion Calendar (not Scheduler).

I got the calendar to work including week view.  But, I cannot find a way to make it pretty.

I wanted to be like this.

[image]

But in Syncfusion, the spaces between the the days (Sunday, monday, etc) and the numbers (7,8,9 etc) is too far apart.  It's like 1 to 2 rows apart.

Please help.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer.
its a simple, wrap it in a grid.

Answer (score -1):

We would like to inform you that as per implementation of SfCalendar, the space between the days in calendar is not reduced or changed.